# Como puedo implementar la subida de un archivo .txt en la estructura Full Rest Api

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, angular, api

Tengo una duda técnica que corresponde a enviar un archivo dentro de la estructura REST FULL API en laravel en este caso en particular lo que estoy trtando de hacer es subir un archivo de texto (.txt) con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"upload",
      "attributes":{
         "archive":[
            
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Como se puede observar en la anterior estructura mi api recibe para todo tipo de solicitud ***POST*** el siguiente formato, pero lo importante aquí es lo que se encuentra en ***attributes***, que en este caso es ***archive***, llega vacio cuando le paso el archivo dentro de la estructura, también se le ha proporcionada los headers a la solicitud ***content-type: "multipart/form-data"***, para poder especificar que es un archivo pero esto no es interpretado por laravel en el siguiente request:

```
public function rules(): array
   {
        return [
            'data.attributes.archive' => ['file','mimetypes:text/plain','required'],
        ];
    }
```

Como podemos analizar esta es la estructura de la regla de validación, pero aclaro, que cuando removemos la estructura de ***RestFullAPI***, cuando quito esa estructura y solo dejo ***archive*** en vez de ***data.attributes.archive*** funciona, pero laravel no interpreta el ***JSON*** cuando lo paso desde la solicitud con la estructura necesaria, no se si es posible mandar archivos de tipo ***file*** dentro de un objeto o si por el contrario hay que hacer algún tipo de conversión para poder tratar de que ***laravel*** lo interprete como un archivo.

**------------- Angular --------------**

Estoy trabajando en la estructura de ResFullApi, y estoy enviando el desde angular de la siguiente estructura, dentro del componente que captura el evento change del archivo tengo lo siguiente:

```
public fileSelected(event): void {
    const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('archive', fileBrowser.files[0], fileBrowser.files[0].name);
    this.rolService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

por lo cual es muy sencillo observar que hago uso de el **new FormData()** para crear la representación de lo que mi compañero muestra que debe tener **archive**, también después yo me dirijo hasta el servicio y envío el archivo desde el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
public uploadFile(archive): Observable<any> | any {
    const format = {
        data: {
          type: 'upload202',
          attributes: {
            archive
          }
        }
      };
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/upload/archive202', format, {
      headers: {
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: esto no lo entiendo: ***para validar el archivo sin que la estructura pase las validaciones de la solicitud para implementar la estructura no sucede.***

Comment: Compañero ya actualicé la información de la pregunta para que la revises.

Comment: https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-file-upload-via-api-example-from-scratch/ mira esto ...

Comment: Amigo lo que sucede es que el archivo se está enviando desde angular y cuando la petición se hace desde el ejemplo que usted me comparte ya funciona, lo que no funciona es dentro la implementación de estructura rest full api

Comment: a ver ... o es laravel o es angular el backend no pueden ser los dos ... si estas enviado los archivos no importa la forma que los envies si esta correctamente implementado tu front no debe por que darte problema el backend...

Comment: validen que $_FILE no este vacio, si lo esta el problema es el front.

Comment: El file solo viene vacio cuando se envia dentro de la estructura Rest Full Api si enviamos la peticion sin la estructura como en el ejemplo que usted agrego funciona correctamente y el cambio, en este caso en particular se envia desde javascript un formData sin la estructura ya especificada arriba y si efectivamente llega, pero el dilema es que cuando se inserta ese file dentro de la estructura.

Comment: JSON no soporta datos tipo `multipart` o `blob`. Tienes que leer el contenido de tu fichero de texto y pasarlo como cadena, pero no estoy seguro que sea eso lo que quieras. Por lo tanto, no veo otra forma más que implementar un endpoint que acepte archivos. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

esta es la solución que implemente y soluciono mi problema, lo que hacía falta era crear un **formdata()** que tuviera la misma estructura que se necesita en el backend, ya que la anterior estructura era un objeto de javascript y me impedía agregar el archivo; con la estructura dentro de este porque para que sea reconocido como un archivo debe tener el header **content-type="multipart/form-data"** y al ser un objeto de javascript no era posible.

**Agrego el código de Angular que me permitió solucionar el error.**

```
public fileSelected(event): void {
    const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data[type]', 'upload202');
    formData.append('data[attributes][archive]', fileBrowser.files[0]);
    this.rolService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

**Contexto el siguiente elemento será el código que espera validar el backend**

```
public function rules(): array
   {
        return [
            'data.attributes.archive' => ['file','mimetypes:text/plain','required'],
        ];
    }
```

**Estructura REST-FULL API a validar**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('POST') || $request->isMethod('PATCH')) {
            $request->validate([
                'data' => ['required', 'array'],
                'data.type' => ['required', 'string'],
                'data.attributes' => ['required', 'array'],
            ]);
        }

        if ($request->isMethod('PATCH')) {
            $request->validate([
                'data.id' => ['required', 'string']
            ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```